# Cannot Convert DbSet<myClass> to DbSet<object>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in my current project where I have a database with some tables.

The easiest to understand is showing the code:

```
Func<DatabaseRef> initDb = (() => //DatabaseRef is my own class, which stores the tables to later add items just over references
{
  MyDb db = new MyDb();
  List<DbSet<object>> tables = new List<DbSet<object>>();
  tables.Add(db.As); //problems on these lines
  tables.Add(db.Bs); //
  tables.Add(db.Cs); //
  tables.Add(db.Ds); //
  return new DatabaseRef(db,tables);
});
```

I try to declare a variable which contiains a function where I have problems.
My Entity Model looks like:

```
public partial class MyDb: DbContext
{
    public MyDb()
        : base("name=MyDb")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //unimportant
    }

    public DbSet<A> As{ get; set; } //where A is my class which describes the table columns
    public DbSet<B> Bs{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> Cs{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<D> Ds{ get; set; }
}
```

I get an error as in the title, but I have no idea why, aren't the instances of my classes from the entity-model normal objects?
I appreciate any help!

**EDIT**:

Basically what I am working on is a project where we have different customers and for each customer I have (or willing to have) a database with multiple tables each. These tables belong to a file which uploads the user in regular inervals. I check the content, delete duplicates and then trying to store the data in the table the file belongs to.
Because this process is identical for each customer and each file/table, my idea was it to have all data belonging to a customer at one place, the `Customer`-class.
That's how I come to the method above, I want the database only to be initialized when required.
That is why I try to be generic, so that I don't have to write the the same lines of code for each customer, so that I can use an universal statement for each item of the list - because all I want to to is update or add data.

Comment: A class generic parameter is not covariant. You can't do that.

Comment: Okay, this is kind of sad. Is there any other way to to what I want or is it comletely impossible?

Comment: Do `A`, `B`, etc.. adhere to a common interface?

Comment: No they don't, it's like `public partial class A { public string columnName { get; set; } }` in every case, the class only has attributes and no methods. I also could not change this since it is auto generated by visual studio

Comment: So could you explain your real "business" need ?

Comment: In what way do you want to use the DbSet items in the list? Do you intend to use the same members on each of them (treat them identically)?

Comment: I've Edited my question. Basically, I have a `Dictionary<>` so I can be 100% sure that I have the correct table, I just made it to a list to be not too complicated